# Converting Text to String and vise-versa in Google App-Engine JAVA

Tags: java, google-app-engine

How can one convert from String to Text

```
java.lang.String
```

to

```
com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Text;
```

and vise-versa?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Check [Javadoc](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/Text.html#getValue()) about `Text` class. It has two methods: `toString()` and `getValue()`.
But `toString()` returns first 70 characters only.

So, use `getValue()` instead:

```
String value = someText.getValue();
```

Contructor of the `Text` class supports initialization with a string value. And (as Javadoc says), this object cannot be modified after construction.