# Convert String to Text (Java Hadoop)

Tags: java, string, text, hadoop

I have the following problem:

I want to split a Text value that I get from a file.

The value format is "12,23"

I want to take the first value in a variable a=12 and the second value in a variable b=23.

I use String.split(","); to do that. The problem is that I want to assign these values in Text variables.

I tried the following and it doesn' t work

```
Text text=(Text) a;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the constructor [`Text(String string)`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/Text.html#Text%28java.lang.String%29):

```
String s = "12,23";
String[] array = s.split(",");
Text t1 = new Text(array[0]);
Text t2 = new Text(array[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track with split.

```
String s;
Text a, b;
s = "12,23";
String[] tokens = s.split(",");
a = new Text(tokens[0]);
b = new Text(tokens[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Create two text variables as:

```
Text a = new Text();
Text b = new Text();
```

... then split the values as:

`String columns[]=value.toString().split("\\\,");`

Finally set the value to text variables as:

```
a.set(columns[0]);
b.set(columns[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
Text text=a.ToString();
```

And see this  same question and answer

[Converting Text to String and vise-versa in Google App-Engine JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819896/converting-text-to-string-and-vise-versa-in-google-app-engine-java)